# Can i change button names for Out-GridView?

Tags: powershell

I have a script which filters an excel sheet (schedule) and displays the result through Out-Gridview. When the user clicks "Cancel" it opens the excel sheet after closing the Out-Gridview. When the user clicks "Ok" it only closes the Out-Gridview. But these actions are not visible for the user. So can i rename the "Ok" and "Cancel" button of Out-Gridview to lets say "Close Schedule" and "Open Excelsheet"? 

And also, is it possible to run the rest of the script without waiting for the response, but keep the buttons working?
I know that if i don't use an output mode the rest of the script runs without waiting, but with outputmode (which gives me buttons) it waits for the response.

I use this code to filter a schedule and it would be nice if i can use the rest of the program without shutting down the rest of the program, maybe by starting another instance of powershell or something?

```bsh
$Schedule = $ResultsTable | Out-Gridview -OutputMode Single -Title "Schedule"
if ($Schedule -eq $Null) {
    Start-Process "$Fileserver\Logistics_share\Planning_Alg\TS Delivery schedule rev2.0.xlsx"
}
```

If it can be done with only a visual overlay, it is ok by me (Buttons)

Comment: No, you can't change the buttons in Out-GridView :)